# Difference of Real numbers and Integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've just started reading 'How to think like a Mathematician'. While explaining the **difference** of of set X and Y, the author presented the following example:

$$
Let \ X = \mathbb{R} \ and\ Y = \mathbb{Z}
$$

$$
X \backslash Y =\ ...\ \cup\ (-3,-2)\ \cup\ (-2,-1)\ \cup\ (-1,0)\ \cup(0, 1)\ \cup\ (1, 2)\ \ ... 
$$

Since, $ \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R} $ And the difference would remove all the $ \mathbb{Z} $, why has the author represented $X \backslash Y$ in the above form?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that every real number is either an integer, or it lies between two consecutive integers. In other words, either $x\in\Bbb Z$ or there is some $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x\in(k,k+1)$.

So the set $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ is really just the points which lie between consecutive integers. This means that this is the union of the intervals $(k,k+1)$ when $k$ ranges over $\Bbb Z$, which can be written as $$\ldots\cup(-3,-2)\cup(-2,-1)\cup(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup\ldots$$

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We can write $\Bbb R=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}[n,n+1]$ and $\Bbb Z=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}\{n,n+1\}$

Thus $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}[n,n+1]\setminus\{n,n+1\}=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(n,n+1)=...\cup(-3,-2)\cup(-2,-1)\cup(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\cup...$

Comment: Nice way to put it. I got confused with the different bracket notations but after revising the previous points in the chapter. I totally get it. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)